# Setting a <StackPanel> background color with Brush

Tags: wpf, brush

So I have created a design with sliders, scrollBars and IntegerUpDowns which all binded togheter move at the same time and have the same value. I have for of each, one for each ARGB. I have a stackPanel in the center which BackgroundColor should change while any of the Tools is modified.

As far as I thought about it, I just need to know one of the tools values in order to set the background through the data they deliver... But how can I implement that ?

So far I have coded this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SolidColorBrush brush;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        brush = new SolidColorBrush();
        brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        stkColor.Background = brush;
    }

    private void scbScrollA_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        brush.Color.A = scbScrollA.Value(); //doesn't work
    }

    private void scbScrollR_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void scbScrollG_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void scbScrollB_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

As I said, just by knowing the scroll data, because I have used Bindings with all the other tools, I could manage to set the color and refresh every single time any data is modified.

The bindings I have:

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="iudB" Increment="10" Minimum="0" Maximum="255"
                                Value="{Binding ElementName=scbScrollB, Path=Value}"
                                />

<ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                   Minimum="0" Maximum="255" x:Name="scbScrollB" 
                   Scroll="scbScrollB_Scroll" SmallChange="1" 
                   LargeChange="10" Value="{Binding ElementName=sliderB, Path=Value}"
                   />

<Slider 
                Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                LargeChange="10" 
                Maximum="255" 
                SmallChange="1" 
                TickPlacement="TopLeft" 
                Minimum="0" 
                TickFrequency="25"
                x:Name="sliderB"
                />
```

The slider doesn't have binding because as far as I know they are bi-directional. None of them gives error.

Comment: Color is a struct, not a class. You must assign a new Color value like this: `brush.Color = Color.FromArgb((byte)scbScrollA.Value, brush.Color.R, brush.Color.G, brush.Color.B);`

Comment: It's WPF, not WinForms. Use data bindings, not event handlers ;-) You could for example use a `<MultiBinding>` for the StackPanel.Background property. The MultiBinding would bind against the 4 Value properties of your ScrollBar controls. The MultiBinding would also have to use a multi-value converter which converts the 4 values from the MultiBinding into a color/brush. You would need to implement this multi-value converter (based on `IMultiValueConverter`). If you don't know about MultiBinding, a web search will surely yield plenty of blog posts and tutorials...

Comment: @Clemens How can I achieve what you are saying? I have changed the constructor: 'brush = new SolidColorBrush();
            brush.Color = Color.FromArgb((byte)scbScrollA.Value, (byte)scbScrollR.Value, (byte)scbScrollG.Value, (byte)scbScrollB.Value);
            stkColor.Background = brush;'

Comment: Put that code in the Scroll event handler.

Comment: @Clemens Fine, it does work with the scrolls because the code is in their events. I was wrong in my initial question, because I'm modifying the sliders or the IntegerUpDowns and which through the bindings modify the scroll but it seems the events don't get the value. Do I have to make a event for all of the tools?

Comment: The Scroll event is only called when you move the ScrollBar's Thumb. Use its ValueChanged event instead. Besides that, better bind all the control properties to a view model, and update the color there. Return the Color value by a public property.

Comment: @Clemens I have updated the post. I'll try to do as you said in this last comment.

Comment: @Clemens Hi, I managed to achieve it. Thank you for your help. If you can, try to put an answer with this last comment. I used the valueChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view model with four byte properties for the four components of a Color, and a `Color` property for the resulting color value.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private byte alpha;
    private byte red;
    private byte green;
    private byte blue;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void SetColorComponent(ref byte field, byte value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (field != value)
        {
            field = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Color));
        }
    }

    public byte Alpha
    {
        get { return alpha; }
        set { SetColorComponent(ref alpha, value, nameof(Alpha)); }
    }

    public byte Red
    {
        get { return red; }
        set { SetColorComponent(ref red, value, nameof(Red)); }
    }

    public byte Green
    {
        get { return green; }
        set { SetColorComponent(ref green, value, nameof(Green)); }
    }

    public byte Blue
    {
        get { return blue; }
        set { SetColorComponent(ref blue, value, nameof(Blue)); }
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue); }
    }
}
```

Assign an instance of the view model to the DataContext of the window and bind the Sliders, ScrollBars, etc. to the view model properties.

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
        </StackPanel.Background>

        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding Alpha}"/>
        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding Red}"/>
        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding Green}"/>
        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding Blue}"/>

        <ScrollBar Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding Alpha}" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        <ScrollBar Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding Red}" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        <ScrollBar Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding Green}" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        <ScrollBar Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding Blue}" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```